# From one string to two, with filter between string

Tags: php

I have this string:

```
[{"position":"1d","number":10,"nb_plot1":12,"max_actions":3}
{"position":"2d","number":7,"nb_plot1":15,"max_actions":30}
{"position":"3d","number":100,"nb_plot1":2,"max_actions":5}]
```

and i need to obtain two different string with different format like this:

for numbers:

```
[10,7,100]
```

for positions:

```
['1d','2d','3d']
```

and cut unnecesarry strings.

I'm a noob sorry.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php you may find this helpful

Comment: do you want to obtain two array not string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode the string in a array with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Iterate over this array and build new arrays for numbers and position.

[Encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the arrays.

In code:

```
$arr = json_decode($string);

$numbers = array();
$positions = array();

foreach($arr as $a) 
{
    $numbers[] = (int)$a->number;
    $positions[] = $a->position;
}

$number_string = json_encode($numbers);
$position_string = json_encode($positions);
```

Comment: @Gore if I put var_dump(json_decode($string, true)); see the array, but with your code I have a blank page

Comment: Yes. I forgot that json_decode return a array of Objects. :/ @user1147636

Comment: @Gore . Ok now number print right, but position_string return Null

Comment: @Gore You lost "s" in $position ....but this code works correctly! Many thanks to all.please correct it for other users.